# How can I use a variable as input in a awk command?

Tags: bash, awk

I have this variable:

```
a='/08/OPT/imaginary/N/08_i_N.out'
```

I want to use "/" as a field separator.

Then, I want to extract the first pattern.

I have tried:

```
awk -F/ '{print $1}' "$a"
```

But I get:

```
awk: cannot open /08/OPT/imaginary/N/08_i_N.out (No such file or directory)
```

I do not want the file, only to work on the path of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way as any other command, either of these (or other alternatives, e.g. within "here-documents" or passed as awk variables or...):

```
printf '%s\n' "$a" | command
command <<<"$a"
```